# display image on mousehover

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table in which there is 1 title and an drop down arrow image in the next column. I want that image to be hidden always and be shown only when the mouse is hovered over it. I tried using :hover attribute but its not displaying the result
My code is something like this.

Edit:

I have achieved the above with the help of opacity attribute. Now what I need to do is to show a dropdown with a link to a page on click of image. I am new to jquery, I have writtent the outline function but clueless as to what to write to display the dropdown with the link.

Here is the function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#ddImg").click(function(){
/// 

    });

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<div class="Table">
    <div class="Row" >
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Dummy Title</p>
        </div>
        <div id="divImg" class="Cell" >
            <img class="image" id= "ddImg" src="images/MENUDARK.gif" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   <style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }

    .image
    {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .cell:hover .image
    {
        opacity: 1;
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: you don't want to use jQuery ?

Comment: There is a typo. Use `.Cell:hover` and not `.cel:hover`

Comment: is this not possible with css? Actually the full functionality will be when move is hovered then the arrow should appear and on click of arrow, a dropdown should appear. I was thinking of adding jquery for the later part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shadeed9/htmv67y6/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="Table">
    <div class="Row" >
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Dummy Title</p>

        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            text here
            <img src="http://img.b8cdn.com/images/templates/bayt/4.0/bayt-logo-new-en.png" class="image"/>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image {
    opacity: 0;
}

.cell:hover .image {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
#arrow img:hover
```

to

```
#arrow:hover
```

In your case selector means "find image in tag with id arrow", but you need "find tag with id arrow"

**UPD** as @somethinghere said, you shoudl change `.cell:hover` to `.Cell:hover`. classNames are casesensitive, so `.cell != .Cell`

Comment: Also, just adding it, but he'd also need to change `.cell` to `.Cell` as his code doesn't really match up. Correct answer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
img#arrow  {
    background-image:url("/images/MENUDARK.gif");
    opacity: 0;
}

img#arrow:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: where should i hover if div is hidden use `opacity` instead

Comment: face-palm :) yes @VitorinoFernandes ! its getting day-end here.. and am getting fuzzy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#ddImg:hover
{
background-image:url("/images/MENUDARK.gif");
}
```

Your `img` tag does not has any thing so cursor is not recognizing it. So add the div id here to make it workable.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ggydvohg/).

Comment: Remove whitespace between `img` and `#` , cause u r trying to find tag with an id "arrow" in image tag right now

Comment: thanks for elaborating. I used opacity and it worked :)

Comment: @DeepikaTyagi My pleasure to help you.